# How to divide $1 in preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to convert all sizes in a html document. Everything with **px should be divided by 4. So 100px would become 25px.

For example:

```
<div style="height:100px;"></div>
```

should become

```
<div style="height:25px;"></div>
```

Here is a php code I wrote. But it doesn't work.

```
$content = "<div style=\"height:100px;\"></div>";
$regex = "#([0-9]*)px#";
$output = preg_replace($regex,"$1/4",$content);
```

How do I do?

Comment: Use preg_replace_callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to `preg_replace_callback`, you can use the `e` modifier to evaluate the replacement as php:

```
$content = "<div style=\"height:100px;\"></div>";
$regex = "#([0-9]*)px#e";
$output = preg_replace($regex,"round($1/4).'px'",$content);
```

Comment: The result is `<div style="height:25;"></div>`. The `px` is missing.

Comment: @bsdnoobz  sorry, forgot to add in the `px`, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php with a callback function like this

```
function divideBy4($m) {
   return ceil($m[1]/4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$content = "<div style=\"height:100px;\"></div>";
$regex = "#([0-9]*)px#";

$output = preg_replace_callback($regex, 
   create_function('$matches', 
   'return ceil($matches[1]/4)."px";'), 
   $content);
?>

<?php
$content = "<div style=\"height:100px;\"></div>";
$regex = "#([0-9]*)px#";
$output = preg_replace_callback($regex, 'myfunc', $content);
function myfunc($matches){
 return ceil($matches[1]/4).'px';
}
?>
```